# CoreData: max number of rows for sort operation?

Tags: ios, performance, core-data

is there a max number of rows that should be in a table to perform a sort operation? I've got a table with a last modified-date on each entry. If I'd like to get e.g. the 50 latest modfiied entries, I first sort by the last-modified-date and then fetch 50 entries. The fetch should be no problem, is there a limit where the sorting could become slow (e.g. > 1 second)?

Thanks a lot,

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the sort descriptor as usual and set your `fetchLimit` to the desired value, core data is going to take care of all the necessary optimizations.

In my experience, for more than 1 second sort time you would need at least tens of thousands of records. Clearly, this depends on hardware and other factors, but you can test it if you want to be sure.